# IOS SWIFT : Change My BarButtonItem Title when one of my Popover cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, popover

Sorry newbie here in IOS Swift. Just want to ask how can i change my BatButtonItem title when one of my Popover cell is selected. Even though I used delegate method. But it still doesn't work for me.

EXAMPLE:
[Here is My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lej6K.png)

Mine doesn't work well here.

HERE IS MY HOMEVC.swift (Whole Code)

```
//
//  HomeVC.swift
//  SwiftLoginScreen
//
//  Created by Dipin Krishna on 31/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dipin Krishna. All rights reserved.

import UIKit
import AFNetworking
import FontAwesome_swift
import KeychainAccess

class HomeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, LanguageViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dashboardOpen: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashboard_icon1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var card_view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_card_view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashboard_icon2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var card_view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_card_view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashboard_icon3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var card_view3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_card_view3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashboard_icon4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var theScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var card_view4: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_dashboard_icon: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_dashboard_icon2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub_dashboard_icon3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTimeLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTimeLabel3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var card_view5: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: NWCalendarView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var ticketBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyWalletBalance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cashWalletBalance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var signupWalletBalance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewStatement1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewStatement2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewStatement3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageTextField: UITextField!

    public static var menuAPI = Json4Swift_Base.init()
    public static var ticketAPI = TicketAPIResponse.init()
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var sections : [Section] = SectionsData().getSectionsFromData()
    public static var tableData: [String] = []
    public static var tableDate: [String] = []
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(108, 0, 110, 64))
    let navItem = UINavigationItem.init(title: "My Home")

    //var pickOption = ["English", "简体", "繁体"]
    //var segmentedControl: HMSegmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["One", "Two"])


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // For UIBar Button Item Title (English) //
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        doLocalize()
        //SwiftSpinner.showWithDelay(0.1, title: "Loading...")
        //SwiftSpinner.hide()

        // For UINavigation Bar //
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0/255.0, green: 164.0/255.0, blue: 161.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
        navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        navigationBar.items = [navItem]
        let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

        calendarView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        calendarView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        calendarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // For Calendar //
        let date = NSDate()
        print(date)
        let newDate3 = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60)
        calendarView.selectedDates = [newDate3]
        calendarView.selectionRangeLength = 1
        calendarView.createCalendar()
        calendarView.scrollToDate(newDate3, animated: true)

        // For Scrolling //
        let subview = theScrollView.subviews[0] as! UIView;
        //Make the scroll view's contentSize the same size as the content view.
        theScrollView!.contentSize = subview.bounds.size;

        // For Side Menu (With Swap) //
        dashboardOpen.target = self.revealViewController()
        dashboardOpen.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        // For Dashboard Icon //
        dashboard_icon1.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(40)
        dashboard_icon1.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-money")
        dashboard_icon2.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(40)
        dashboard_icon2.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-money")
        dashboard_icon3.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(40)
        dashboard_icon3.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-money")
        dashboard_icon4.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(40)
        dashboard_icon4.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-clock-o")
        sub_dashboard_icon.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
        sub_dashboard_icon.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-arrow-circle-o-right")
        sub_dashboard_icon2.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
        sub_dashboard_icon2.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-arrow-circle-o-right")
        sub_dashboard_icon3.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
        sub_dashboard_icon3.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-arrow-circle-o-right")

        // For Dashboard Radius //
        card_view1.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        card_view1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        let path1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:sub_card_view1.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.path = path1.CGPath
        sub_card_view1.layer.mask = maskLayer1

        card_view2.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        card_view2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        let path2 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:sub_card_view2.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5))
        let maskLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer2.path = path2.CGPath
        sub_card_view2.layer.mask = maskLayer2

        card_view3.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        card_view3.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        let path3 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:sub_card_view3.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5))
        let maskLayer3 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer3.path = path3.CGPath
        sub_card_view3.layer.mask = maskLayer3

        card_view4.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        card_view4.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        card_view5.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        card_view5.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        calendarView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        calendarView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        // For Dashboard Current Time //
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: Selector("tick"),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func changeName(text: String) {

        self.barButtonItem.title = "\(text)" // For get barButton you should create IBOutlet for barButtonItem
        print(self.barButtonItem.title)

    }

    @objc func tick() {

        let date1 = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter1 = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
        let timeZone1 = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT+8")
        dateFormatter1.timeZone = timeZone1

        let date2 = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let timeZone2 = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT+8")
        dateFormatter2.timeZone = timeZone2


        currentTimeLabel.text = dateFormatter1.stringFromDate(date1)

        currentTimeLabel2.text = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(date2)

        currentTimeLabel3.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(),
            dateStyle: .NoStyle,
            timeStyle: .MediumStyle)

        var day:String = ""
        day = currentTimeLabel2.text!

        if (day.containsString("Sunday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Sunday")
        }
        else if (day.containsString("Monday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Monday")
        }
        else if (day.containsString("Tuesday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Tuesday")

        }
        else if (day.containsString("Wednesday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Wednesday")
        }
        else if (day.containsString("Thursday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Thursday")
        }
        else if (day.containsString("Friday")){

            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Friday")
        }
        else{
            currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("Saturday")
        }
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)


        let parameters1 = ["ActionType":"default","LanguageCode":stringLang,"Token":result]
        manager.POST(CONFIG_URL,
            parameters: parameters1,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                var responseDict = responseObject as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                let dashboardAPI = DashboardAPIResponse(dictionary: responseDict)


            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })


        let parameters = ["ActionType":"menu","LanguageCode":stringLang,"Token":result]
        manager.POST(CONFIG_URL,
            parameters: parameters,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                var responseDict = responseObject as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


                HomeVC.menuAPI = Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: responseDict)
                var tempArray = HomeVC.menuAPI?.result


                for var i = 0; i < tempArray!.count ; ++i {
                    let level1 = tempArray![i].module
                    let level2 = tempArray![i].subModule

                    for var i = 0; i < level1!.count ; ++i {
                        print(level1![i].icon)
                        print(level1![i].label)

                    }

                    for var i = 0; i < level2!.count ; ++i {
                        print(level2![i].label)
                        var level3 = level2![i].function

                        for var i = 0; i < level3!.count ; ++i {
                            print(level3![i].label)
                            print(level3![i].menuLink)
                            print(level3![i].uRL)

                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func doLocalize(){

        companyWalletBalance.text = Localization("companyWalletBalance")
        cashWalletBalance.text = Localization("cashWalletBalance")
        signupWalletBalance.text = Localization("signupWalletBalance")
        currentTimeLabel2.text = Localization("currentTimeLabel2")
        viewStatement1.text = Localization("viewStatement")
        viewStatement2.text = Localization("viewStatement")
        viewStatement3.text = Localization("viewStatement")
        navItem.title = Localization("navItem")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return sections[section].heading
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        // Text Color
        var header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView)
        header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return sections.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return sections[section].items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sectionsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
            mycell.label1.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
            mycell.label2.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
            mycell.label3.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
            mycell.label4.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
            return mycell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }


    @IBAction func languageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
        var menuViewController: LanguageViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LanguageViewController") as! LanguageViewController
        menuViewController.delegate = self // Put this Line
        menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 100)

        let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
        popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = menuViewController.view
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x:240, y:35, width: 1, height: 1)
        presentViewController(menuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func dashboardLogout(sender: AnyObject) {

        let parameters = ["ActionType":"logout"]
        manager.POST(CONFIG_URL,
            parameters: parameters,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                // CLEAN COOKIES //

                let cookie = NSHTTPCookie.self
                let cookieJar = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
                for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
                    print(cookie.name+"="+cookie.value)
                    cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
                }

                var revealViewControler :SWRevealViewController =  self.revealViewController()
                let webViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController

                revealViewControler.pushFrontViewController(webViewController, animated: true)


            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })

    }


}

// For Date + Time //
extension NSDate {
    var formattedd:String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
    func formatteddWith(format:String) -> String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

// For Date + Time //
extension String {
    var asDatee:NSDate! {
        let styler = NSDateFormatter()
        styler.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return styler.dateFromString(self)!
    }
    func asDateFormatteddWith(format:String) -> NSDate! {
        let styler = NSDateFormatter()
        styler.dateFormat = format
        return styler.dateFromString(self)!
    }

}
```

HERE IS MY LANGUAGEVIEWCONTROLLER.swift (Where display the content of Popover)

```
//
//  LanguageViewController.swift
//  SwiftLoginScreen
//
//  Created by User on 3/21/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Dipin Krishna. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AFNetworking

protocol LanguageViewControllerDelegate{
    func changeName(text:String)
}

class LanguageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var delegate:LanguageViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    var arrLanguage: [String] = ["English", "简体", "繁体"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        delegate!.changeName(arrLanguage[indexPath.row])
        tableView.delegate = self

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrLanguage.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:LanguageTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LanguageTableViewCell") as! LanguageTableViewCell

        cell.languageLabel.text = arrLanguage[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // For Popover Frame Size //
    override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get
        {
            return CGSize(width: 150, height: 130)
        }
        set
        {
            super.preferredContentSize = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

HERE IS MY LANGUAGETABLEVIEWCELL.swift

```
//
//  LanguageTableViewCell.swift
//  SwiftLoginScreen
//
//  Created by User on 3/21/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Dipin Krishna. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class LanguageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var languageLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

When i try to debug this part of code, when my code run, it doesn't go through this code. why ?

```
func changeName(text: String) {

        self.barButtonItem.title = "\(text)" // For get barButton you should create IBOutlet for barButtonItem
        print(self.barButtonItem.title)

    }
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: You need to implement a delegate process here so your languageTableViewController can tell the base that you've changed the language and what language it has changed to. This is very fundamental design pattern which is asked many times on stackoverflow and covered in endless tutorials around the web.

Comment: @DavidWong yeah i know but i don't know how to start with the delegate. Sorry for still abit confusing with the delegate. Can show me step by step ?

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/ is what you want.

Comment: @DavidWong so i should delegate my HomeVC.swift or LanguageViewController.swift or my tableView ?

Comment: Try the tutorial in your code, make mistakes and try again. If I answer this one you'll not figure out all the great things you can do with this design pattern.

Comment: @DavidWong okay Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Make a protocol in the LanguageViewController that you will be sending the data.

```
protocol LanguageViewControllerDelegate{
    func changeName(text:String)
}
```

**Step2:** Declare the delegate in the sending class (i.e. HOMEVC)

```
class LanguageViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:LanguageViewControllerDelegate! = nil
   [...]
 }
```

**Step3:** Use the delegate in a class method to send the data to the receiving method, which is any method that adopts the protocol.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     delegate!.changeName(arrLanguage[indexPath.row])
 }
```

**Step 4:** Adopt the protocol in the receiving class

```
 class HomeViewController: UIViewController,LanguageViewControllerDelegate { }
```

**Step 5:** Implement the delegate method ( HomeViewController - as in your Problem )

```
func changeName(text: String) {
    self.barButton.title = "\(text)" // For get barButton you should create IBOutlet for barButtonItem
}
```

**Step 6:** Set the delegate in the action button for the BarButtonItem for Popover:

```
   @IBAction func languageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
        var menuViewController: LanguageViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LanguageViewController") as! LanguageViewController
        menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 100)
        menuViewController.delegate = self // Put this Line
        let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
        popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = menuViewController.view
        popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x:240, y:35, width: 1, height: 1)
        presentViewController(menuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Yoy should put tableView delegate and datasourse in viewDidLoad() :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self 
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

And tableView didSelectRow :-

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate!.changeName(arrLanguage[indexPath.row])
}
```

And Hope that this gonna work ....

Comment: this is only change the title which hardcoded, but i want it like when i pressed my popover selected cell, my barbuttonitem will change based on the selected cell.

Comment: there is an error in step 4, which the "LanguageViewControllerDelegate" got error. It said "Type HomeVC does not conform to protocol "LanguageViewControllerDelegate""

Comment: yeah because you should do step 5 for clear that error. Think this delegate one as tableviewDelegate. You should insert table view delegate methods in the view controller to work that table. So this delegate method also act like that. you've create  func changeName(text:String) in the language view so you should call that function on HomeVC

Comment: Yeah I put already by following all your step but still got the same error. Is there anything I missed out ?

Comment: Yeah just look at the step 5 ... I changed the name. Please change the name as func changeName(text: String)

Comment: it still not working :( the problem is still the same, which my UIBarButtonItem title still doesn't change the text when i select my popover table cell.

Comment: no more error. but my UIBarButtonItem text still does not change

Comment: Oppzz again my error , changed step 5, not text , it should self.barButton.title. Now this should work !!!

Comment: you mean like this ?

func changeName(text: String) {
        
        self.barButtonItem.title = self.barButtonItem.title // For get barButton you should create IBOutlet for barButtonItem
        
    }

Comment: self.barButton.title = "(text)" not self.barButton.text = "(text)"

Comment: put Print(text) in func changeName(text: String) { } and comment the output

Comment: And please update your question and put the complete HOMEVC.swift code

Comment: added the print(), it doesnt go through that part of code. I don't know why. And also i updated my whole code for the HomeVC.swift.

Comment: Did you add menuViewController.delegate = self // Put this Line in step 6 ?? and also step 3 ??? Update the LanguageViewController also

Comment: step 6 i followed de, put already. step 3 you mean put in this code that you show ? 

delegate!.changeName(arrLanguage[indexPath.row])

Comment: Yeah , update the question and put languageViewController code also

Comment: tableView.delegate = self .... this line should put in viewDidLoad().Put tableView.delegate = self & tableView.dataSource = self in  viewDidLoad()

Comment: Ok changed again step 6 , have a look...BTW Put tableView.delegate = self & tableView.dataSource = self in viewDidLoad()

Comment: not working also. Is it because my storyboard problem ?

Comment: Hmmm I double checked my solution , it's right but didn't figure out the problem. Finally try to delete popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self in step 6 and update your code as i updated

Comment: And another thing check whether that tableView didselectRow function trig when you click the language. Put print("clicked") in tableView didSelectRow function

Comment: checked. the print("clicked"0 doesn't appear which mean the tableview(didSelectRow) method doesn't go through

Comment: you mean i should set it on the storyboard there ?

Comment: when i edited your given step 6 answer, now when i pressed the UIBarButtonItem Title, another page, which is the LanguageViewController will come up and cover my whole previous screen. but still the tableview function doesn't work, even though i put in print()

Comment: Ok undo that , but problem is you didn't correctly set up the table .... This method is the correct way to do. But try to delete the whole table and try this one. Problem is with your table